# Aurora serverless connection timed out

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

I'm trying to connect to my aurora serverless but every time I try to do it I receive this error:

```
2021/03/18 17:10:00 error verifying database connection is alive: dial tcp 10.247.15.113:3306: connect: operation timed out exit status 1
```

I created a VPC, subnets and security groups.

- VPC -> 10.247.0.0/20
- 4 Subnets -> 10.247.0.0/22, 10.247.8.0/22, 10.247.4.0/22 and 10.247.12.0/22
- Security group -> Lives inside my VPC and as inbound has port SSH 22 for 0.0.0.0/0 and MYSQL/Aurora 3306 for my EC2 instance IP address. Outbound has all traffic

Using ssh in a database client works but inside my code I receive the error I mentioned, I also tried doing telnet and I receive another operation timed out.

I know this may be something related to the networking but not sure why since I can connect via ssh with an EC2 instance. What can it be?

Comment: Can you clarify? You want to connect to the Aurrar serverless from home/work? Or from an ec2 instance?

Comment: Please remove the `go` tag.

Comment: @Marcin I'm trying to connect from home and I followed this setup for the coding part: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/UsingWithRDS.IAMDBAuth.Connecting.Go.html#UsingWithRDS.IAMDBAuth.Connecting.Go.AuthToken

Answer (score 1):

Your guide is for RDS. It does not apply to Aurora Serverless (AS). Specifically AS **can't be accessed from internet**. So you [can't connect](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/aurora-serverless.html) to it directly from home:

> You can't give an Aurora Serverless v1 DB cluster a public IP address. You can access an Aurora Serverless v1 DB cluster **only from within a VPC**.

You have to connect to it from within a VPC, e.g. EC2 instance, ECS container or a lambda function.

The only way to connect to it from home is to use [RDS DataAPI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/data-api.html), or setup **ssh tunnel** or VPN between your home network and your VPC.

Comment: So by having a vpn that allows me to connect to my vpc will I me able to execute the code since it does have a cluster endpoint? @marcin

Comment: @user2737948 Yes, because connections will be done using private IP addresses, not public ones.